# Kubernetes DNS resolving via host alias

Tags: kubernetes, dns

it there for Kubernetes an option to set a DNS alias as in can be done within a host file (62.116.156.20 servera)? Where servera is an external server. As a result any pod within the cluster can get in contact to server via DNS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends how you configure and deploy your pods. There is an option to add a custom DNS entry to the host file of every pod documented here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/

configuration snip:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
  containers:
  - name: cat-hosts
    image: busybox:1.28
    command:
    - cat
    args:
    - "/etc/hosts"
```

Comment: Thus a pod individual configurations is necessary and there is no option to provide a cluster wide config which can be applied to each current and future deployment?

Comment: @ChristianV AFAIK the only option to make the whole cluster aware of the IP address is to setup a DNS server and configure the IP there. There is some documentation over here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/